# What's the meaning of "be-" prefix?

Tags: meaning

Keep this example:

http://www.wordreference.com/deen/beachten

http://www.wordreference.com/deen/%C3%A4chten

achten means respect

beachten means obey

What's the meaning of the prefix be? What is changing in a word when you introduce that prefix?

Comment: This link should be helpful.. http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/german-prefixes-explanation-be/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I quote from DWDS, (same link I actually gave in you other question)

> Die Vorsilbe dient namentlich der Transitivierung intrans. Verben, z. B. begehen, beleuchten, besiegen, doch können mit ihr (nach dem Muster präfigierter Denominativa wie bekränzen, beschützen) auch Verben zu Substantiven (z. B. beeinflussen, benachrichtigen, besohlen, bevölkern) oder zu Adjektiven (z. B. befähigen, beruhigen) gebildet werden. Außerdem ermöglicht sie es, Adjektive, die die Form von Partizipien haben ( ‘mit etw. ausgestattet’), unmittelbar von Substantiven abzuleiten, wenn kein entsprechendes Verb vorhanden ist, z. B. bebrillt, beherzt, beleibt. Dagegen ist die Zahl mit be- präfigierter Adjektive gering (s. bequem, bereit, bieder).

So, it converts an intransitive verb into transitive, i.e. now it accepts an accusative-object.